# Unhandled Rejection (Error): A cross-origin error was thrown. - ReactJs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-hooks, cross-domain

I'm facing a strange issue in my React application. Whenever I set the value of a state variable, application throws the following error:

```
Unhandled Rejection (Error): A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have access to the actual error object in development. See https://reactjs.org/link/crossorigin-error for more information.
```

I'm running Node.js on the server side with following configs:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors')({ origin: '*' });

const app = express();
app.use(cors);

app.get('/v1/products', (request, response) => {
    response.send(JSON.stringify(onlineStoreProducts));
});
```

It is returning following headers, upon request:

```
access-control-allow-headers: "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
access-control-allow-origin: "*"
content-encoding: "gzip"
content-type: "text/html; charset=utf-8"
date: "Thu, 11 Feb 2021 00:04:11 GMT"
etag: "W/"521-MMsS1cPRJzAF2U2F3Sjg90rr4Q0""
vary: "Accept-Encoding"
x-powered-by: "Express"
```

From client side, I'm using Axios to request the server using following code:

```
axios.get(BASE_URL + '/v1/products').then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
    updateProducts(response.data);
});
```

Function `updateProducts(products)` has the following definition:

```
const [products, setProducts] = useState(null);

const updateProducts = (products) => {
    setProducts(products);
};
```

Now, whenever this hook gets executed, it throws the error. How do I know that `setProducts(products);` is throwing the error? I changed it to `setTimeout(() => setProducts(products).bind(this), 5000);` and it  resulted in causing error exactly after 5 seconds of getting the response (I printed the log). I even tried changing it to `setProducts(JSON.stringify(products));`, that also prevented the error.

I understand why CORS error occurs and that's why I configured my server to include * in the headers but, it seems that this error is not happening because of actual CORS concept.

Am I missing something here? Let me know if more details are required.

Comment: Try adding a .catch on your axios req and log the error. What do you get when you log the response? Check the status code maybe.

Comment: Its not getting into catch block. Axios is making successful request. I get a 200 response from the server, console is even printing response.data successfully. Issue is definitely not related to server-client networking. It has something to do with the react-hooks, I just don't know what.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue. Doing nothing unusual, just a fetch request and state update. For some reason getting the same error even if the request returns the right response.

Answer (score 0):

I've just experienced the same issue a while ago. Problem was I was getting wrong response from server (an array of table rows instead of a single row), therefore the data weren't compatible with my state structure.

Why does React throws such a weird error I don't know.